Maximum update depth exceeded when clicking on element
ProgressMinimalIconsConnected is a component that shows a step-by-step instruction to the user, in which a certain number of steps are displayed. In the mobile version, I display a tooltip for each step. The tooltip disappears by setTimeout. If the user needs the tooltip to appear again, they can click on the step.
Problem: if the tooltip is still displayed above the current step and I click on the step, I get an error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops. If the tooltip has disappeared, then there is no such error. The error occurs only with the current step.
export type ProgressMinimalIconsConnectedProps = ProgressStepProps & { 
    connectorClassName?: string, 
    isTooltipOpen?: boolean, 
    tooltipDuration?: number 
};

export const ProgressMinimalIconsConnected = memo( forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, ProgressMinimalIconsConnectedProps>( ( { size = "sm", className, currentStep = 0, isTooltipOpen, tooltipDuration, connectorClassName, ...props }, ref, ) => { 
    const [ activeStep, setActiveStep ] = useState(0);
    const [ tooltipOpen, setTooltipOpen ] = useState(false); 
    const isMobileView = useIsMobileView();  

 useEffect(() => {
    setActiveStep(currentStep);
    if (isMobileView) {
      const isOpen = currentStep === 0 || currentStep !== -1;
      setTooltipOpen(isOpen);

      const time = setTimeout(() => {
        setTooltipOpen(false);
      }, tooltipDuration);

      return () => clearTimeout(time);
    }
  }, [ currentStep, isMobileView ]);

  const handleStepClick = (index: number) => {
    if (isMobileView) {
      setActiveStep(index);
      setTooltipOpen(true);
      const time = setTimeout(() => {
        setTooltipOpen(false);
      }, tooltipDuration);
      return () => clearTimeout(time);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div
      className={classnames(styles.root, className)}
      {...props}
      ref={ref}
    >
      {props.steps.map((item, index) => (
        <div className={styles.container} key={item.id}>
          <Tooltip
            content={item.text}
            supportingContent={item.supportingText}
            isOpen={isTooltipOpen && isMobileView && activeStep === index && tooltipOpen}
            placement={"top"}
          >
            <StepBase
              {...item}
              id={`${item?.id}`}
              size={size}
              type={"iconOnly"}
              status={getIndicatorState(index, currentStep)}
              onClick={() => handleStepClick(index)}
            />
          </Tooltip>
          {index < props.steps.length - 1 && (
            <div className={classnames(styles.connector, connectorClassName, {
              [styles.connectorComplete]: index < currentStep,
            })}></div>
          )}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
},
), );

No possible solution comes to mind yet.

This file looks fine to me. Is there an effect in your Tooltip or StepBase components that updates some state it also depends on?
